# How to remember selected values in Multiple choice Alert Dialog?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog, android-checkbox

I am using AlertDialog with Multiple choice to show list of check-able items.

When user selects some of values, I can get theirs index and save it to list. That is working fine.

But I want when user again open AlertDialog to have selected/checked values that he selected before.

Here is the code:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.array_cousine, null,
            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected,
                                    boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        seletedItems.add(++indexSelected);
                    } else if (seletedItems.contains(indexSelected)) {   
                        seletedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(++indexSelected));
                    }
                }
            })
            // Set the action buttons
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {  
                    String[] expList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_cousine);

                    for (int i = 0; i < seletedItems.size(); i++) {
                        int selected = seletedItems.get(i);
                        String selectedString = expList[selected - 1];
                        selectedItemsName.add(selectedString);
                    }

                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    for (int j = 0; j < selectedItemsName.size(); j++) {
                        String text = selectedItemsName.get(j);
                         stringBuilder = stringBuilder.append(" "+text);

                    }

                    Log.d("TAG", "String builder: " + stringBuilder);
                    tvCusine.setText(stringBuilder);

                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    Dialog dialog = builder.create();//AlertDialog dialog;
    dialog.show();
```

Here is the picture:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second parameter in `builder.setMultiChoiceItems` is a `boolean[]` that you are currently passing in as null. To show items as checked when it opens pass in this array with `true` in the position of each item that you want to be checked. These values can be set after the array is created using `boolean[position] = value`

Comment: Yeah I know that second parameter accepts boolean, I passed null since I do not know how to dynamically add values to boolean[].

Comment: You can't dynamically change the size. You can change the values whenever you want by calling boolean[position] = value. You could also have an arraylist of Booleans and then calling arraylist.toArray when you create instantiate the alert dialog –  Marcus Hooper 13 secs ago   edit

Comment: I have tried the second solution and it does not work. I will try first solution now.

Comment: Second solution works. Edit your answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at docs for [setMultiChoiceItems](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setMultiChoiceItems(java.lang.CharSequence[],%20boolean[],%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener)) second argument is boolean array in which you set which items are checked and which are not. You are passing null, therefore, nothing will be checked.

Comment: I know that, but is possible to dynamically change values of boolean[]?